# ASP MVC - CSS Image Sprites into a View

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a huge css file (Content/Site.css) which includes also more than 200 lines of spirits.

I wanna make a View/PartialView which shows all my sprites images ( many divs ) .

How I do it?

How to read and parse css file in code behind from a controller and then put my result into a ViewBag?

Or there is no need to parse from server side and just show it from client side?

```
div.feedImgPop,
div.feedImg,
div.feedImgList { background: url("http://xxx/Sprite.jpg") top left no-repeat; }        
div.a{ background-position:0 0; }
div.b{ background-position:0 -43px; }
```

... 200 lines..

- asp net mvc 4.5

Update :

- Splited CSS file into 2 files , sprite and the rest
- Used CSS Parser to read the sprite css file from a controller
- Show the sprite images as shown below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this css parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335850/CSSParser)

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {      
        parser.ReadCSSFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Sprite.css"));
        var cssItems = new List<String>(cssList.Count);
        foreach (var item in cssList) cssItems.Add(item.Key.Replace("div.", ""));
        ViewBag.items = cssItems;
        return View();
    }
```

View :     ( CSS Solution - I use this )

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.items)
            {
                string className = "imgContainer imgHover feedImgPop " + @item;
                <div class="@className" onClick="adminChooseSpriteImage('@className')"></div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

View  : (Table Solution - 10 items each row ; previous test )

```
<div id="feedsContainer">
    @{
        int rowNumber = 1;
        <table>
            <tr>

               @foreach(var item in ViewBag.items)
                {

                    if (rowNumber % 11 == 0)
                    {
                          <tr></tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          string className = "imgContainer imgHover feedImgPop " + @item;
                         <td><div class="@className"></div></td>
                    }

                    rowNumber++;
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```